# matplotlib - Shunt x-axis labels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have data in a numpy record array:

```
a = np.array([(29.40818036, '1'), (34.96458222, '2'), (16.05225074, '3'),
       (13.23025364, '4'), (6.340924671, '5+')], 
       dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', 'S2')])
```

And I'm plotting a bar graph like this:

```
plt.bar(np.arange(5)+0.5,a['f0'],width=1,color='0.95')
plt.ylim(0,40)
plt.xlim(0.5,5.5)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(a['f1'])
```

Giving:

[image]

Note the x-axis values do not align correctly with the bars, the first value in `a['f1']` is missing (`'1'`).

`a['f1']` is `['1' '2' '3' '4' '5+']` - I was expecting these 5 strings to placed underneath the five bars. However, they are shunted to the left by one and the `'1'` drops off. I am looking for a way to 'shunt' the values to the right.

**What is the best way to adjust the x-axis tick labels?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the tick positions first:

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(5) + 1.)
ax.set_xticklabels(a['f1'])
```

Comment: For me setting `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(5) + 1.5)` and  `plt.xlim(1,6)` worked. Thanks